# Eclipse RCP problem

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I used a third-part view in my RCP application,there is a TreeViewer in this view.
I want to add a handler to handle the tree node selection event, how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether the third party view provides any API to access the treeviewer. If it does then get the treeviewer and directly add the listener